# Uncorrected behavior of transform-origin in safari browser

Tags: javascript, css, safari, cross-browser, css-animations

JS slider. The functionality is based on `transform-origin:` and `transform: rotateY` Appearance and code below. In all browsers is displayed correctly (as on the photo below). In Safari `transform-origin` does not work correctly. (second photo)

[in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj55X.png) [mast be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsYk3.png) [css styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xwQd.png)

```
if (document.querySelector(".carousel")) {
  console.log("CIRCLE");

  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    var carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel");
    for (var i = 0; i < carousels.length; i++) {
      carousel(carousels[i]);
    }
  });

  function carousel(root) {
    var figure = root.querySelector("figure"),
      nav = root.querySelector("nav"),
      images = figure.children,
      n = images.length,
      gap = root.dataset.gap || 0,
      bfc = "bfc" in root.dataset,
      theta = (2 * Math.PI) / n,
      currImage = 0;
    setupCarousel(n, parseFloat(getComputedStyle(images[0]).width));
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      setupCarousel(n, parseFloat(getComputedStyle(images[0]).width));
    });

    setupNavigation();

    function setupCarousel(n, s) {
      var apothem = s / (2 * Math.tan(Math.PI / n));
      figure.style.transformOrigin = `50% 50% ${-apothem}px`;
      // gsap.to(figure, { transformOrigin: "50% 50% 1200px" });

      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) images[i].style.padding = `${gap}px`;
      for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        images[i].style.transformOrigin = `50% 50% ${-apothem}px`;
        images[i].style.transform = `rotateY(${i * theta}rad)`;
      }
      if (bfc)
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) images[i].style.backfaceVisibility = "hidden";

      rotateCarousel(currImage);
    }

    function setupNavigation() {
      nav.addEventListener("click", onClick, true);

      function onClick(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        var t = e.target;
        if (t.tagName.toUpperCase() != "BUTTON") return;

        if (t.classList.contains("next")) {
          currImage++;
        } else {
          currImage--;
        }

        rotateCarousel(currImage);
      }
    }

    function rotateCarousel(imageIndex) {
      figure.style.transform = `rotateY(${imageIndex * -theta}rad)`;
    }
  }
}
```

Safari has a different `transform-origin`, although through the dispatcher all styles are the same as in other browsers. Perhaps there are differences in the behavior of this property? Can you show me by example what these differences are?
On the advice tried to use `transform-box: fill-box`, but there is no difference and I dont understand how it can help. Also tried to put `transform-origin:` different values, but as far as I can see safari does not accept negative values. Perhaps there is some hook how to achieve the same functionality but without `transform-origin`? Or is it still possible to implement cross-browsing? I will be glad to hear advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you do not post images as links; instead, just paste where  you want it to show up.